# PHP and JSON for Reddit

Tags: php, json, reddit

want to grab from a specific Reddit user some data.

There's a dynamic JSON file on the Reddit servers which can be accessed remotely.

The JSON file path is: http://www.reddit.com/user/tiagoperes/about.json

(where you can replace “tiagoperes” in the URL with whatever user you were trying to look up) - *thank you Tom Chapin*

**Problem**: I get the error message

> http error 500: reddiant.com/reddit.php

**Error Log:**

> PHP Warning:
> file_get_contents(https://www.reddit.com/user/tiagoperes/about.json):
> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden on
> line 5
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException'
> with message 'Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty
> array instead' on line 8

**Code**:

```
<?php


$url = "https://www.reddit.com/user/tiagoperes/about.json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);

$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

(inspired in this: http://codepad.org/Gtk8DqJE)

**Solution**: Ask for debug.

*What's the problem right here?*

Can not find a way to make it work and should be quite straightforward.

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what does `**Problem:** the page doesn't even load.` mean

Comment: Ok so `file_get_contents()` is not on **line 7** of the code you are showing us. **Show us the real code, if you want a real answer**

Comment: check again, there was:
<?php phpinfo(); ?>

on top

Comment: If you are going to **fake the line number** 1) We can see an edit history and 2) `file_get_contents()` is not on **line 5 of the code you show either**

Comment: If you are doing a `phpinfo()` then show me what is in this parameter in the display `Loaded Configuration File`

Comment: Again? In php.ini it has, and I'm sure:

allow_url_fopen = On

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was getting some troubles in the first procedure, so decided to change the approach.

Got it to work like that:

```
<?php
    $opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"User-Agent: reddiant api script\r\n"
    ));

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $url = "http://www.reddit.com/user/tiagoperes/about.json";
    $json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    $result = json_decode($json, true);

    // Result:
    var_dump($result);

    //echo data
    echo $result['data']['name'];
```